# Insert key-value pair into array composed of key-value pair

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let a = [
 { title: coke, price: 10},
 { title: soda, price: 20},
 { title: lime, price: 30},
 { title: olive, price: 30},
]
```

This is what I want

```
let b = [
 { title: coke, price: 10, owner: 'Amy'},
 { title: soda, price: 20, owner: 'Amy'},
 { title: lime, price: 30, owner: 'Amy'},
 { title: olive, price: 30, owner: 'Amy'},
]
```

my code and it works!

```
a.map(data => {
return {
 title: data.title,
 price: data.price,
 owner: 'Amy'
 }
})
```

But more elegant and fast way if the length of a is more than a million?

Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: do you expect to produce a new array or to update the existing array with adding a new property ?

Comment: both, can you please give me examples? It would be helpful!

Comment: [see my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124436/insert-key-value-pair-into-array-composed-of-key-value-pair/68124854#68124854)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spread the object being iterated over into a new one, plus a new key.

```js
let a = [
 { title: 'coke', price: 10},
 { title: 'soda', price: 20},
 { title: 'lime', price: 30},
 { title: 'olive', price: 30},
]
console.log(
  a.map(obj => ({ ...obj, owner: 'Amy' }))
);
```

Also note that you'll need string delimiters for the `title` values.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply just add the key in the map.

```js
a.map(data => {
  data.owner = 'Amy';
  return data;
})
```

Here is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-monad-iln5l?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

update the same array:

```js
let a = 
  [ { title: 'coke',  price: 10 } 
  , { title: 'soda',  price: 20 } 
  , { title: 'lime',  price: 30 } 
  , { title: 'olive', price: 30 } 
  ] 

a.forEach(o=>Object.assign(o,{owner: 'Amy'}))

console.log('a =', a )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

but in this the more simple is

```
a.forEach(o=>o.owner = 'Amy')
```

create a new array:

```js
let a = 
  [ { title: 'coke',  price: 10 } 
  , { title: 'soda',  price: 20 } 
  , { title: 'lime',  price: 30 } 
  , { title: 'olive', price: 30 } 
  ] 

let b = a.map(o=>Object.assign({},o,{owner: 'Amy'})) // o stay unchanged

console.log('a=', a )
console.log('b=', b )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```